# *ngIf not working inside *ngFor rendering empty elems? ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I'm trying to develop an ionic app that will handle different arrays of objects, and although I know the type of object I'm reading (location, business card, etc) and which fields that type of object must have I will need to add dynamically the unknown fields to process them differently from the know fields. In this case that I'm currently working, I only want the value of the card["address"] to show up (later I will add other things that's why I don't want to do  `<ion-card-content [class]="key" *ngIf="card['address']">{{card["address"]}} </ion-card-content>`
So, in this example, I want to loop through the keys in the object card and show for instance, the value of address.

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="cards.length > 0;">
    <ion-list no-border>
      <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let card of cards" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <ion-card color="#3E4D5C" class="card" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <div  *ngIf="card.location;" style="height:175px; width: 100%" [id]="'map_canvas'+card['pos']"></div>
          <img  *ngIf="card.EMAIL;" [src]="card.IMG" style="width: 100%;height: auto;max-height:20%;object-fit: cover;">
          <ion-card-content *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(card)">
              <ion-card-content *ngIf="card.location;">
                  <ion-card-content [class]="key" *ngIf="key === 'address'">{{card[key]}} </ion-card-content>    
              </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card-content>
```

What I'm expecting is something like this:
[image]

But what happens is this:

[image]

Where the empty space is basically empty divs like this:

```
<ion-card-content _ngcontent-ulj-c1="" class="md card-content-md hydrated" __plugindomid="pgm1300845537375"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "\u000047,5"
}--><ion-card-content _ngcontent-ulj-c1="" class="md card-content-md hydrated" __plugindomid="pgm291174209756"><!--bindings={}--></ion-card-content></ion-card-content>
```

My ionic info

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.21
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1
```

What I'm i doing wrong?

Comment: what data is in the cards collection?

Comment: The rendered text looks the same in both screenshots, the only different seems to be the height of the space between the map and text. Is the issue that excess spacing?

Comment: @hunter  here is an example of cards
````
[{"location":"\u000047,5","x":"\u000047","y":"5","info":"geo","pos":0,"address":", Unnamed Road, Corberon, Bourgogne-Franche-Comté, 21250, France"}]
```

@AlexanderStaroselsky exactly, but in this case, the empty space is just empty divs that matches  the number of keys in the array that should be hidden

Comment: Instead of <ion-card-content *ngIf="card.location;">, try <ion-card-content *ngIf="card.location !== null">

Comment: hi @Lok, same result as before.

Comment: try card.location !== ''

Comment: @Mauro like that it wont work, I just get a white screen in the device due to  Unexpected end of expression: card.location !== at the end of the expression

Comment: are you sure? this should work: `*ngIf="card.location!==''"`
use double quotes outside and single quotes inside

Comment: @MauroSemproni like this ```<ion-card-content *ngIf="card.location !== ''">``` it wont give an error but I get the same result as I did before :(

Comment: I think the problem is that you have card.location, so it correctly shows the card-content, but that content is empty 'cause there is not card.address. try: `<ion-card-content [class]="key" *ngIf="key === 'address' && card.address !==''">{{card[key]}} </ion-card-content>`

Comment: @MauroSemproni thanks for helping out,  but that also didnt work. Based on your feedback I also tried to change to ``` <ion-card-content *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(card)">
                  <ion-card-content [class]="key" *ngIf="key === 'address' && card.address !==''">{{card[key]}} </ion-card-content>   
          </ion-card-content> ``` 
Basically removed the location bit,and exactly the same result

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to display. you loop over all the attributes of the card, but you wanna show only the address? Then why do you loop? Plus you should'nt duplicate che ion-card content, you should have just one content with, maybe, a list in it. Could you please explain better, updating the question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MauroSemproni I will update the question, but just to give a quick answer, I don't want to just show the address, the idea is to fetch data, that although presented in the form of an array of objects, I don't always know the keys presented in the object. for instance, let's say that I received a object that is related to a location, I know that in that array I will have an address and coordinates, but I also could have other keys that will like to present in the format key:object[key]. Like locations I can receive objects related to business cards,etc.

Comment: Ok, I will change the duplication of ion-card content, maybe thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `objectKeys(card)` this will parse every attributes inside `card` object and since `card.location` is defined for every keys this will show blank space for each key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="cards.length > 0;">
    <ion-list no-border>
      <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let card of cards" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <ion-card color="#3E4D5C" class="card" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <div  *ngIf="card.location;" style="height:175px; width: 100%" [id]="'map_canvas'+card['pos']"></div>
          <img  *ngIf="card.EMAIL;" [src]="card.IMG" style="width: 100%;height: auto;max-height:20%;object-fit: cover;">
              <ion-card-content *ngIf="card.location;">
                  <ion-card-content [class]="key" *ngIf="key === 'address'">{{card[key]}} 
              </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ion-card-content component contains a card-content-md class which includes padding set to

```
 padding: 13px 16px;
```

This padding is being applied to each key the *ngFor loops over